# How do I automate finding the coefficient of variation for multiple categories?

Tags: r

In my data I have 1000 measures for each spatial unit and would like to plot the coefficient of variation of each of these units. I know how to calculate the coefficient of variation for the entire data set, but how would I:

**1) Create a function that will grab all category names (unique values in a column).**

**2) Apply the CV function to only those data in each category**

**3) Output the results so they can be plotted as x=category and y=CV**

The Iris data set can be used as an example. Lets say I'd like to know the coefficient of variation of petal length for each species. The CV itself is simple enough, but I'm at  loss for the rest of it.

```
data(iris)
CV <- function(mean, sd){
  (sd/mean)*100
}
IrisCV <- CV(mean=mean(iris$Petal.Length), sd=sd(iris$Petal.Length))
IrisCV
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you should change your function to:

```
CV <- function(x){
        (sd(x)/mean(x))*100
}
```

Then you can use `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(Petal.Length ~ Species, 
          data = iris,
          FUN = CV)
#     Species Petal.Length
#1     setosa    11.878522
#2 versicolor    11.030774
#3  virginica     9.940466
```

Comment: perfect thank you. Just to make sure I understand: the edit to the function was to cut down on text right? not necessarily because there was an inherent syntax issue in my original code?

Comment: Your initial function works, but it is inefficient because it doesn't exactly calculate  `CV`, just divides your two inputs by each other `*100`. Second of all, both inputs are calculated from the same vector, so it is better to simplify and move the entire operation inside the function. The you can `aggregate()` easily.